# Use rx to highlight a specific group in a match

Tags: font-lock, rx

I am trying to write a major mode for a language, and I am working on the syntax highlighter.  I am using `rx` with some success, however I need to highlight the following pattern:

```
`somemacro(args...)`
```

Using non-emacs regex, I could write something like

```
(?:`)\w+(?:`\(.*\))
```

However, I am finding it difficult to do this with `rx` with [no shy/non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084083/).

I have tried the following:

```lisp
(eval-and-compile
  (defconst my-macro-names-regexp
    (rx "`" (group (one-or-more word)) (seq "(" (zero-or-more anything) ")" "`"))))

(defconst my-highlights
  `(,(const my-macro-names-regexp font-lock-function-name-face)))
```

But this highlights the whole match (I only want to highlight the group):

[image: wrong output]

But I am hoping to only highlight the macro name itself:

[image: correct output]

(Note that, in this screenshot, the parentheses and arguments of the macro are highlighted with a different highlighting rule, so can be ignored.)

Comment: You specify the group number. See the font-lock doc in the Elisp manual, or see the question that this is essentially a duplicate of (see the accepted answer, which matches specific groups).

Comment: Hi @Drew, yes, that question uses the same logic of specifying the group number that solves my question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can specify a group that you want to match on as follows:

```lisp
(eval-and-compile
  (defconst my-macro-names-regexp
    (rx "`" (group (one-or-more word)) (seq "(" (zero-or-more anything) ")" "`"))))

(defconst my-highlights
  (list
   ;; Extract 1st group from regex
   (list my-macro-names-regexp 1 font-lock-function-name-face)))
```

I haven't found this documented anywhere, but I found it used [here](https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-emacs/blob/7a8c868e0d3e51ba4a2c621ee22ca9599e0e4bbb/julia-mode.el#L330).  I'll update this answer if anyone can find documentation for this feature.

Comment: Please clarify which part of this is not documented.  `group` is certainly documented in the doc-string of `rx`.  Meanwhile, specifying a submatch is in the doc-string of `font-lock-keywords`.

Comment: Hi @FranBurstall, I was referring to not being able to find documentation on specifying a specific group match.  Please provide a link and I can update my answer.